# Linked webparts filter

Tags: web-part, filter, view

I have a page with 2 linked webparts, actually 2 list views. (One view is simply sending a parameter to the other view).

My problem is that when I use the list filter (by clicking on the view column) and there is just one record, it is automatically selected but the other view is not filtered.

In Chrome it is working fine. (the record is not selected and by clicking it, the other view is filtered).

Any tips?